# How to use a regular expression and assign the result to variables in Android?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a string named `s_Result` which will be parsed from the Internet. The format may be `"Distance: 2.8km (about 9 mins)"`, and there are 4 variables which are `f_Distance`, `m_DistanceUnit`, `f_timeEst`, `m_timeEstUnit`.

My question is how to parse `s_Result` and assign `2.8`, `km`, `9`, `mins` into `f_Distance`, `m_distanceUnit`, `f_timeEst` and `m_timeEstUnit` respectively using regular expression?

I tried using `"\d+(\.\d+)?"` in RegEx Tester and the result showed 2 matches found, but if I use `"\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"` in Android code, it showed no matches!

Any suggestions what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like that?

```
String s_Result="Distance: 2.8km (about 9 mins)";

//Distance parsing
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Distance: (\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)(.*?)\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s_Result);
if(m.find()){
    MatchResult mr=m.toMatchResult();
    f_Distance=mr.group(1);//2.8
    m_DistanceUnit=mr.group(3);//km
}

//Time parsing
p = Pattern.compile("about (\\d+(\\.\\d+)?) (.*)\\b");
m = p.matcher(s_Result);
if(m.find()){
    MatchResult mr=m.toMatchResult();
    f_timeEst=mr.group(1);//9
    m_timeEstUnit=mr.group(3);//min
}
```

And here's another option for you, to match more flexible format:

```
String s_Result="Distance: 2.8km (about 9 mins)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?) ?(\\w+?)\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s_Result);
while(m.find()){
    MatchResult mr=m.toMatchResult();
    String value=mr.group(1);//2.8 and 9 come here
    String units=mr.group(3);//km and mins come here
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want!!!!  
How idiot I am that forgot to use `"\b"`...  

Thank you so much^^

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using `"\d+(\.\d+)?"` in RegEx Tester and the result showed 2 matches found, but if I use `"\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"` in Android code, it showed no matches!

Probably you was using [`String#matches()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) or [`Matcher#matches()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) which would match on the *entire* string. The regex is then actually `"^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$"`. Better use [`Matcher#find()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) instead.

```
String s = "Distance: 2.8km (about 9 mins)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0)); // 2.8 and 9
}
```

That said, have you considered writing a parser?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!  
You are right, i was using `Matcher.matches()`. And your code works fine!!    
I do consider to write a parser, but there are some problems exist.  
The major problem is that I can not make sure the format of `s_Result`. All I know is there must exist 2 sets of data in the sting, which including numbers and its unit.  
  
Do you have any idea how to get the unit followed by the numbers??  
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

**It's absolutely the same as in Java.**

Really, most of Android questions are not related to Android itself, but to Java programming in general. Please try to search for more general questions before posting new 'Android' questions.